# What are the difference b/w three keys given inside function in AzureFunction app

Tags: azure-functions

After creating `AzureFunction app` I created three functions in that app. Now when I click on any of that function I will have `Get function URL` button on the right side when I click on it one pop up shown up. In that pop up there is one drop-down button for function `Key` and one Text box for `URL`.

In that key drop-down there are three type of key

1. default (Function key)
2. _master (Host key)
3. default (Host key)

What is the difference between those three keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> API keys are may be defined at two distinct levels:
>
> **Host**: Also commonly referred to as Function App Level keys. Keys
> defined at this level apply to the entire Function App. You have the
> ability to define Function Keys at this level, and they would allow
> clients to authenticate against any function. This is also where your
> Master Key is defined.
>
> **Function**: Function level keys apply to the
> specific functions they're defined under, restricting its use for
> authentication to that function only. To enable key rolling and
> consumer specific keys, you can define multiple named keys at the host
> and/or function levels.
>
> API keys are persisted, encrypted, on the file system under
> D:\home\data\Functions\secrets, in files matching the function name
> for function level keys, and a file named host.json for the host level
> keys.
>
> **Master Key**
>
> The master key provides administrative access to the runtime APIs. You
> should exercise care if you choose to use the Admin authorization
> level for your functions as we do not recommend redistributing the
> master key.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki/Http-Functions#user-content-api-keys